How to filter data in d365 Storcommerce POS ResumeCart Screen
I want to filter the data that appears in the ResumeCart screen by the user who suspended the transaction so that the user only shows his transactions.
I found a filter function and expected it would do the job and wrote the following code.

import * as ResumeCart from "PosApi/Extend/Views/ResumeCartView";
import { IExtensionCommandContext } from "PosApi/Extend/Views/AppBarCommands";
import { ObjectExtensions } from "PosApi/TypeExtensions";
import { GetLoggedOnEmployeeClientRequest, GetLoggedOnEmployeeClientResponse } from "PosApi/Consume/Employees";
export default class ResumeCartFilterByUser extends ResumeCart.ResumeCartExtensionCommandBase {
    private _state: ResumeCart.IResumeCartExtensionCommandState;
    private _isFiltered: boolean = false;

    constructor(context: IExtensionCommandContext<ResumeCart.IResumeCartToExtensionCommandMessageTypeMap>) {
        super(context);

        this.id = "LogicFilterByUser";
        this.label = "Filter By User";
        this.extraClass = "iconLightningBolt";
    }

    protected init(state: ResumeCart.IResumeCartExtensionCommandState): void {
        this._state = state;
        this.isVisible = true;
        this.canExecute = true;
    }

    protected async execute(): Promise<void> {
        this._isFiltered=!this._isFiltered;
        if (this._isFiltered) {
            const employeeResponse =
             await this.context.runtime.executeAsync(new GetLoggedOnEmployeeClientRequest<GetLoggedOnEmployeeClientResponse>());
            if (!ObjectExtensions.isNullOrUndefined(employeeResponse) && !employeeResponse.canceled  )
            {
             const employeeId = employeeResponse.data.result.StaffId;
              this._state.suspendedCarts.filter(cart => cart.suspendedCart.Cart.StaffId === employeeId);
            }
            else
            {
                this._isFiltered = false;
            }
        } 
    }
}


But when the order is executed, there are no changes to the records displayed
I know that I may be using the function incorrectly, but I searched and did not find any example of filtering data, I hope you give me an example of filtering data or correct the code to work and filter the data

add the framwork tag to the question to display it to more relevant users and get your answer faster.
